# How can get free space by using Autovacuum Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
pgbootdb=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('pgbootdb'))
 pg_size_pretty
----------------
 804 MB

pgbootdb=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('fruit_type'))
pgbootdb-# ;
 pg_size_pretty
----------------
 410 MB

pgbootdb=# update fruit_type set id = id+1;
UPDATE 6291450

pgbootdb=# delete from fruit_type where id between 1000 and 1200;
DELETE 1206
 
pgbootdb=# select n_dead_tup ,last_vacuum,last_analyze,n_tup_upd, n_tup_del,n_tup_hot_upd,relname  from pg_stat_all_tables where relname='fruit_type';

 n_dead_tup | last_vacuum | last_analyze | n_tup_upd | n_tup_del | n_tup_hot_upd |  relname   |
------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------------+
     
 1206 |                   |                  |   6291450 |      1206 |          1066 | fruit_type |
```

```
autovacuum = on                                               
log_autovacuum_min_duration = -1      
autovacuum_max_workers = 3              
autovacuum_naptime = 1min             
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 50        
autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 50       
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2    
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1  
autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age = 400000000 
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 2ms     
autovacuum = on_vacuum_cost_limit = -1
```

Dead tuple and analyze was still present.

Comment: Don't post text as images of text.  And do put a question in your question.

Answer (score 0):

## How to calculate when autovacuum will vacuum

In order for autovacuum to vacuum the `fruit_type` table, you will need to exceed the two thresholds called `autovacuum_vacuum_threshold` and `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor`.

You have `autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 50`, meaning that 50 rows need to be updated or deleted, and `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2`, meaning that 20% of the table needs to be updated or deleted before autovacuum will vacuum the table.

20% of your table is `0.2 * 6,291,450 = 1,258,290`, so you will need to update or delete `1,258,290 + 50 = 1,258,340` rows before autovacuum will vacuum the `fruit_type` table.  More information about these two parameters can be found in the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html)

## Clearing up misunderstandings about [auto]vacuum

Since the post is titled "How can get free space by using autovacuum postgresql," it is necessary to dispel some misunderstanding about how autovacuum/vacuum works.  `VACUUM` alone does not reclaim space -- it merely marks dead tuples as reusable for future `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations.  `VACUUM FULL`, however will reclaim space, much like defragmenting a disk; bear in mind that `VACUUM FULL` will take an exclusive lock on a table, and therefore should be used with care, so as not to disrupt client application performance.  In the example below, it can be seen that `VACUUM` does not reclaim space, even though `n_dead_tup` has been reduced to `0`:

```
edb=# create table mytest (id int, name text);
CREATE TABLE
edb=# insert into mytest values (generate_series(1,1000000),md5(random()));
INSERT 0 1000000
edb=# select n_dead_tup ,last_vacuum,last_analyze,n_tup_upd, n_tup_del,n_tup_hot_upd from pg_stat_user_tables where relname = 'mytest';
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+--
n_dead_tup    | 0
last_vacuum   | 
last_analyze  | 
n_tup_upd     | 0
n_tup_del     | 0
n_tup_hot_upd | 0

edb=# select pg_size_pretty( pg_relation_size('mytest'));
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+------
pg_size_pretty | 65 MB

edb=# delete from mytest where id % 3 = 0;
DELETE 333333
edb=# select pg_size_pretty( pg_relation_size('mytest'));
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+------
pg_size_pretty | 65 MB

edb=# select n_dead_tup ,last_vacuum,last_analyze,n_tup_upd, n_tup_del,n_tup_hot_upd from pg_stat_user_tables where relname = 'mytest';
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+-------
n_dead_tup    | 333333
last_vacuum   | 
last_analyze  | 
n_tup_upd     | 0
n_tup_del     | 333333
n_tup_hot_upd | 0

edb=# vacuum mytest ;
VACUUM
edb=# select n_dead_tup ,last_vacuum,last_analyze,n_tup_upd, n_tup_del,n_tup_hot_upd from pg_stat_user_tables where relname = 'mytest';
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+---------------------------------
n_dead_tup    | 0
last_vacuum   | 29-JUL-21 06:07:12.629155 +00:00
last_analyze  | 
n_tup_upd     | 0
n_tup_del     | 333333
n_tup_hot_upd | 0

edb=# select pg_size_pretty( pg_relation_size('mytest'));
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+------
pg_size_pretty | 65 MB

edb=# vacuum full mytest ;
VACUUM
edb=# select pg_size_pretty( pg_relation_size('mytest'));
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+------
pg_size_pretty | 43 MB
```